# What does the notation $\pi_n(X) = 0$ and $\pi_n(X) = 1$ mean for a homotopy group?

Tags: algebraic-topology, definition, fundamental-groups

For any path-connected space $X$, the set $\pi_n(X)$ is the set of homotopy equivalence classes of continuous functions $f:S^n \to X$ (some authors use loops instead). $\pi_n(X)$ is also a group under the operation $*$. Thus, we can discuss isomorphisms between $\pi_n(X)$ and other groups. For instance, $\pi_1(S^1) \cong \mathbb{Z}$. I recognize that some authors (rather lazily in my opinion) will right this as $\pi_1(S^1) = \mathbb{Z}$. However, what does the notation $\pi_n(X) = 0$ and $\pi_n(X) = 1$ mean?

**Edit:** For some clarification for where I pulled these notations out of, I got them from these two statements from my topology class:

> If $X$ is a contractible space, then $\pi_n(X) = 0$ for all $n \ge 0$.
>
> A  topological  space $X$ is  called simply connected if it is path connected  and $\pi_1(X) = 1$.

Comment: Is there some more context in which you are seeing this? $0$ surely refers to the zero group (a.k.a. the trivial group or the group on one element). I'd bet $1$ refers to $\mathbb Z$ (a.k.a. the free group on one element or the free abelian group on one element) - but that's more doubtful without more context.

Comment: @MiloBrandt For the context of $\pi_n(X) = 1$, it came from the definition of simply connected in my class (i.e. $X$ is simply connected if $X$ is path connected and $\pi_1(X) = 1$). The instructor does not follow a textbook, but recommends Hatcher, so perhaps from there.

Comment: Your definition of the homotopy groups isn't right (the restriction to path-connected spaces is irrelevant and one has to impose an equivalence relation to turn the set of functions into a group). That aside, because the fundamental group $\pi_1(X)$ is not necessarily commutative, it is common to use multiplicative for it (so the trivial group is 1). It is common to use additive notation for the higher homotopy groups (so the trivial group is 0)

Comment: So that means $1$ also refers to a trivial group. (Often people use $0$ for trivial when thinking additively, and $1$ for trivial when thinking multiplicatively.)

Comment: Thank you @RobArthan, I corrected that. I will remark that my instructor note that the notation $\pi_n(X)$ is meaningless unless $X$ is a path-connected space (we are working within the context of pointed homotopy groups). I recognize that path-connectedness is irrelevant to this discussion.

Comment: Technically it's more accurate to write $\{0\}$ instead of $0$, but omitting the braces is a common abbreviated notation.

Comment: So in this context, $0$ really does equal $1$... Well, kinda

Comment: @bounceback: the way I think of it is that 0 is used to denote the group $(\{0\}, 1, +)$ with carrier set $\{0\}$, unit $0$ and multiplication $+$. Likewise $1$ denotes $(\{1\}, 1, \times)$. They aren't equal, but they are isomorphic. (Note that technically $\{0\}$ and $\{1\}$ aren't groups, but just sets. However, outside model theory and universal algebra, the notation distinction between groups and their carrier sets is often blurred.)